# OpenStack Installation without virtualbox

Tags: openstack

Is there any way to install OpenStack without using virtual box in a single machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a possibility of installing openstack(both 2 and 3 node architectures) in a single system. But, things are to be considered. Like the performance of the system used, the primary memory associated with it, the secondary memory that is available, e.t.c

Answer (score 1):

You can install all openstack services(controller, compute, network) in a single node. But it's not recommended.

If you don't want to install virtualbox you can try [VMware](http://www.vmware.com/)

You may also try [LXC](https://linuxcontainers.org/) or [XEN](http://www.xenproject.org/) if you are using linux. Then create 3 virtual machines and install openstack 3 node configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course. Just make sure you have enough resources on the system (single machine) to bare OpenStack. You may use packstack do the All-in-One
deployment. Check out [RDO](https://web.archive.org/web/20170606180424/https://www.rdoproject.org/install/quickstart/).

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about development environment, sure! You don't need a VM at all, and can just install it on your laptop directly! Note that this is not a desirable configuration :)

Other ways are to use a different virtualization tool than VirtualBox, like KVM, or VMware stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual machine is nothing but a system with shared resources. Whatever we do on a VM can be replicated to an  individual system.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have VT enabled on the hardware , else you may have issues in creating instance on the Compute node.

Regards, 
Amit Manel

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you can install in single virtual machine , can also be installed on your machine directly. 
After all your machine is much more powerful and stable than your virtual machine.

We use virtual machine just to leave our system intact in case something goes wrong. Just compare the time it would take you to delete and create another virtual machine with time and effort for formatting your entire laptop.

Also, we sometimes use virtual machine if we need to make a network of 2-3 computers for some functionality and we have got only one hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I created with kvm virtual machünes on Ubuntu 14.04
If you create the virtual machines and the virtual networks you can use it.

For the easiest way if you use an orchestration/deployment tool e.g. Mirantis Fuel

Answer (score 0):

Surprising no body talked about Dockers. You can run openstack in a docker container.

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience, always try to install openstack on a fresh system( either on a freshly created VM or on a newly installed OS). I have installed openstack many times, and trust me no error will come just follow [this link](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/devstack/guides/single-machine.html) on a newly setup machine. For old system, I was stuck for 3 days, and only GOD knows where from the hell those errors were showing up.

PS: I have always tried **ubuntu system**.